# Are there any benchmarks for CUDA-GPU or for MPI-CPU+CUDA-GPU?

Tags: c++, cuda, mpi, benchmarking, gpgpu

Are there any benchmarks such as ["NAS parallel benchmark"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAS_Parallel_Benchmarks), but for CUDA-GPU, MPI-CPU+CUDA-GPU or (OpenCL GPU+CPU), and where can I take its?

As I know, an example there is [HPL(High Performance Computing Linpack Benchmark for CUDA)](https://github.com/avidday/hpl-cuda) for MPI-CPU+CUDA-GPU. This is modified version of ["HPL - A Portable Implementation of the High-Performance Linpack Benchmark for Distributed-Memory Computers"](http://www.netlib.org/benchmark/hpl/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MAGMA is a CUDA-based BLAS library.

http://icl.utk.edu/magma/

Its source code contains a large set of testing programs for BLAS1,2,3 and LAPACK rotines, which can be used as benchmark test for SMP-CPU v.s. CUDA-GPU.

By using different makefiles, it can compare the performance of several BLAS/LAPACK libraries on both SMP-CPU and CUDA-GPU.

1. CPU libs: MKL, GotoBLAS, ATLAS, ACML
2. GPU libs: CUBLAS, MAGMA

And MAGMA also has multi-GPU support.

Here's a sample output of its `testing_dgemm`

```
$ ./testing_dgemm -l
MAGMA 1.4.0 , capability 3.0
device 0: Tesla K20m, 705.5 MHz clock, 4799.6 MB memory, capability 3.5
Usage: ./testing_dgemm [options] [-h|--help]

If running lapack (option --lapack), MAGMA and CUBLAS error are both computed
relative to CPU BLAS result. Else, MAGMA error is computed relative to CUBLAS result.

transA = N, transB = N
    M     N     K   MAGMA Gflop/s (ms)  CUBLAS Gflop/s (ms)   CPU Gflop/s (ms)  MAGMA error  CUBLAS error
=========================================================================================================
 1088  1088  1088    542.60 (   4.75)     885.12 (   2.91)     16.09 ( 160.07)    4.02e-15     4.02e-15
 2112  2112  2112    594.08 (  31.72)    1013.63 (  18.59)     17.80 (1058.40)    5.58e-15     5.58e-15
 3136  3136  3136    595.65 ( 103.55)    1014.95 (  60.77)     67.72 ( 910.87)    7.64e-15     7.64e-15
 4160  4160  4160    591.86 ( 243.27)    1030.00 ( 139.79)     86.60 (1662.71)    8.79e-15     8.96e-15
 5184  5184  5184    589.67 ( 472.52)    1035.98 ( 268.95)     91.06 (3059.81)    1.06e-14     1.06e-14
 6208  6208  6208    583.73 ( 819.73)    1044.25 ( 458.23)     95.69 (5000.59)    1.18e-14     1.19e-14
 7232  7232  7232    585.58 (1291.86)    1044.57 ( 724.21)     99.09 (7634.04)    1.15e-14     1.15e-14
 8256  8256  8256    586.20 (1919.98)    1045.94 (1076.05)     98.31 (11447.84)    1.21e-14     1.21e-14
 9280  9280  9280    585.82 (2728.40)    1046.96 (1526.67)     99.49 (16064.95)    1.54e-14     1.54e-14
10304 10304 10304    586.37 (3731.41)    1048.27 (2087.26)    100.38 (21797.19)    1.67e-14     1.67e-14
```

Comment: As I understand MAGMA-source-code(magma-1.4.0.tar.gz) contain "MAGMA provides implementations for CUDA, OpenCL, and Intel Xeon Phi" and comparison tests for MAGMA, CUBLAS and ATLAS. And also something libs for Xeon Phi, is it MPI or OpenCL?

Comment: And if I want to use HPL in clusters where many CPU+GPU by using MPI, do I must using MAGMA in standard HPL, or MAGMA already contain this test for cluster through MPI?

Comment: @Alex Xeon Phi is Intel's many-core HPC solution, similar to CUDA for Nviida's GPU. And I don't know much about Magma's MPI support.